# Best way for implement method chaining (fluent interface) with model class

Tags: java, model-view-controller, java-8, fluent-interface, method-chaining

How to implement method chaining for model class in web application?

I have clean POJO model class:

```
public class MyModel {
    private String property;

    public String getFirstProperty() {
        return property;
    }

    public void setFirstProperty(String firstProperty) {
        this.property = firstProperty + "blah blah";
    }

}
```

And I want to add two methods. Where I should add them?

```
public MyModel doSomething(String something) {
    property += something + "blah";
    return this;
}

public MyModel doAntyhing(String antyhing) {
    property += antyhing + "blah blah";
    return this;
}
```

I want use their like this:

```
MyModel myModel = new MyModel();
myModel.doAntyhing("blah").doAntyhing("blah blah");
```

---

Below my poor, ugly solutions. How to do it better?

---

**First way.** Easy way, but very ugly for model class (they should be clean, without logic application):

```
public class MyModel {
    private String property;

    public String getFirstProperty() {
        return property;
    }

    public void setFirstProperty(String firstProperty) {
        this.property = firstProperty;
    }

    public MyModel doSomething(String something) {
        property += something + "blah";
        return this;
    }

    public MyModel doAntyhing(String antyhing) {
        property += antyhing;
        return this;
    }
}
```

I want to move these two method to other class.

```
public class LogicForMyModel {
    public MyModel doSomething(String something) {
        property += something + "blah";
        return this;
    }

    public MyModel doAntyhing(String antyhing) {
        property += antyhing + "blah blah";
        return this;
    }
}
```

But how connect these two class? Maybe I should use inheritance or interface? How?

```
interface ILogicModel {
    public MyModel doSomethingLogic(String something);
    public MyModel doAntyhingLogic(String antyhing);
}
```

---

**Second way.** Use "builder" (solution based on [this](http://code.runnable.com/Uvbmi7Dm2bQHAAAu/how-to-implement-fluent-interface-in-java)).

```
public class MyModel {
    protected String property;

    public String getFirstProperty() {
        return property;
    }

    public void setFirstProperty(String firstProperty) {
        this.property = firstProperty;
    }

    public BuilderMyModel build() {
        return new BuilderMyModel(this);
    }

}

public class BuilderMyModel {
    private MyModel myModel;

    public BuilderMyModel(MyModel myModel) {
        this.myModel = myModel;
    }

    public BuilderMyModel doSomething(String something) {
        myModel.property += something + "blah";
        return this;
    }

    public BuilderMyModel doAntyhing(String antyhing) {
        myModel.property += antyhing + "blah blah";
        return this;
    }
}
```

Then I can use this (probably build() is like stream() in Java 8):

```
MyModel myModel = new MyModel();
myModel.build().doAntyhing("blah").doAntyhing("blah blah");
```

It's better way than first. But I must use method build(). And I would like to invoke methods for MyModel instead of Builder (as in LINQ in C#).

It is the way to do it better?

---

**Third.** Using library [fluent-interface-proxy](https://github.com/davidmarquis/fluent-interface-proxy). But I don't want to use external library for everyday. Otherwise in this way I must use method for build like in second way.

Comment: You should use builder only if these methods will be used, in fact, to build the model object. Maybe you should give us more context about what these methods will do. Is it a simple operation with one of the model's properties? Is it a business logic?

Comment: I don’t see anything worth a discussion. In one case, you have a certain logic implemented in one class, in the second, you have *the same* logic spread over two classes. The logic doesn’t change, so neither variant is better than the other. If you really think, the number of methods in one class matters (more than the number of classes), well, then distribute the methods over two or more classes. If not, well, do whatever you like. There is no real difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a Functional interface like follow:

```
interface ModelModifier {
    void apply(MyModel model);
}
```

Then, implement some modifiers you need:

```
static ModelModifier doSomething(String something) {
    return model -> model.setProperty(something + "blah");
}

static ModelModifier doAntyhing(String anything) {
    return model -> model.setAnything(anything);
}
```

and add somewhere a method which applies modifiers, maybe directly in MyModel class like this:

```
void applyModifiers( ModelModifier ... modifiers) {
    Stream.of( modifiers ).forEach( m -> m.apply(this) );
}
```

And now, you can call

```
mymodel.applyModifiers( doSomething( "blah" ), doAnything( "blahblah") );
```

It is not exactly method chaining, but it can be used instead of method chaining

Comment: The `doSomething`/`doAnything` methods should be static to be used like this (with static imports). Also the `return null` should be removed as your `apply()` method has a `void` return type.

Comment: @DidierL You are prefectly right, i fixed that